# Classes e métodos estáticos podem ser usados no ASP.NET MVC sem problemas entre sessões de usuários?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, classes

Fiz uma rotina de *login* utilizando *cookies* e como sempre estou buscando essas informações, pra não precisar ficar instanciando em todos os lugares que vou usar deixei essas classes estáticas, minha dúvida é se vai ter algum problema quando mais de um usuário for fazer *login*.

Aqui é código do *controller*:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(string email, string senha)
    {
        //Verifica se as credenciais estão validas, se não estão retorno a tela de login.
        if (!AutenticacaoHelper.AutenticarUsuario(email, senha, Session))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", new { Erro = "0" });
        }

        //se esta logado, redireciono para a view carrinho
        return RedirectToAction("Carrinho", "Produto");
    }
```

Aqui é o código da `AutenticacaoHelper`

```
public static class AutenticacaoHelper
{
    public static bool AutenticarUsuario(string email, string senha, HttpSessionStateBase Session)
    {
        ClienteDAO _clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();

        cliente Cliente = _clienteDAO.Autenticar(email, senha);

        if (Cliente == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            GerarSessao(Session, Cliente);
            CarrinhoHelper.AtualizaClienteCarrinho(Cliente);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static void GerarSessao(HttpSessionStateBase Session, cliente cliente)
    {
        //gero um token de sessao concatenando 2 tokens
        var tokenSessao = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token.ToString() + Session.SessionID.ToString();
        SessaoDAO _sessao = new SessaoDAO();
        _sessao.AdicionaSessao(cliente.id, tokenSessao);
        //Cria o cookie de sessao EFETIVAMENTE
        CookieHelper.RegistraCookieAutenticacao(tokenSessao, cliente.email);
    }
}
```

Aqui o código do `CookieHelper`

```
public class CookieHelper
{
    public static void RegistraCookieAutenticacao(string tokenSessao, string email)
    {
        //Crio o token de sessao.
        HttpCookie CookieDeSessao = new HttpCookie("TokenDeSessao", tokenSessao);
        CookieDeSessao.Expires = DataHelper.DataAtual().AddMonths(3);

        //Crio o token com email
        HttpCookie CookieDeEmail = new HttpCookie("EmailDoCliente", email);
        CookieDeEmail.Expires = DataHelper.DataAtual().AddMonths(3);

        //Adiciono o cookie no contexto da aplicação
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(CookieDeSessao);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(CookieDeEmail);
    }

    public static string BuscaCookieCarrinho()
    {
        try
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("TokenDoCarrinho").Value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui o `CarrinhoHelper`

```
public static class CarrinhoHelper
{
    public static void AtualizaClienteCarrinho(cliente Cliente)
    {
        string tokenCarrinho = CookieHelper.BuscaCookieCarrinho();

        if(tokenCarrinho != null)
        {
            PedidoDAO _pedidoDAO = new PedidoDAO();

            _pedidoDAO.AtualizaClientePedido(tokenCarrinho, Cliente);
        }
    }
}
```

aqui é a ClienteDAO que faz a busca do cliente no banco de dados

```
public cliente Autenticar(string email, string senha)
    {
        try
        {
            using (_contexto = new EnvidroEntidades())
            {
                //Busco o cliente
                var cliente = _contexto.cliente
                    .Where(u => u.email == email)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                //Se o cliente não existe ou a senha criptografada não bate, não autentico o usuário
                if (cliente == null || !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(senha, cliente.senha))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    //criar a sessao do usuario
                    return cliente;
                }
            }
        }
```

E aqui é a classe que atualiza o pedido que não tem `id` de cliente depois de fazer o login:

```
public void AtualizaClientePedido(string tokenCarrinho, cliente Cliente)
    {
        try
        {
            using (_contexto = new EnvidroEntidades())
            {
                var pedido = _contexto
                                    .pedido
                                    .Where(p => p.token_pedido == tokenCarrinho && p.situacao == "Carrinho")
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (pedido != null && pedido.id_cliente == null)
                {
                    pedido.id_cliente = Cliente.id;
                    _contexto.Entry(pedido).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _contexto.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //api
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma usada não tem problema, estas classes existem para isto mesmo, criar códigos que serão chamados de forma universal na aplicação. Pelo menos olhando por cima não tem com que se preocupar, você está apenas delegando, não vi detalhes para afirmar que poderia haver problemas, mas se tiver não será porque é estático. Vi algumas coisas que eu provacvelmente faria diferente, mas só.

Comment: Valeu, era só essa dúvida mesmo, só por curiosidade o que vocês faria diferente ? gosto de saber outras formas de fazer as coisas, acredito que é melhor do que o jeito que estou fazendo